# RedBean returns null when unboxing model from bean?

Tags: php, orm, redbean

I can't get the `box()` method to work, I only get `NULL` from it.

For example if I do this

```
$bean = \R::load('comment', 2);

print("\n\nBEAN:\n");
var_dump($bean);

$model = $bean->box();

print("\n\nMODEL:\n");
var_dump($model);
```

I get this

```
BEAN:
class RedBeanPHP\OODBBean#68 (10) {
  protected $properties =>
  array(4) {
    'id' =>
    string(1) "2"
    'user' =>
    string(1) "2"
    'reply_to' =>
    NULL
    'message' =>
    string(30) "Test comment 1"
  }
  protected $__info =>
  array(4) {
    'type' =>
    string(7) "comment"
    'sys.id' =>
    string(2) "id"
    'sys.orig' =>
    array(5) {
      'id' =>
      string(1) "2"
      'user' =>
      string(1) "1"
      'reply_to' =>
      NULL
      'message' =>
      string(30) "Test comment 1"
    }
    'tainted' =>
    bool(false)
    'changed' =>
    bool(false)
  }
  protected $beanHelper =>
  class RedBeanPHP\BeanHelper\SimpleFacadeBeanHelper#17 (0) {
  }
  protected $fetchType =>
  NULL
  protected $withSql =>
  string(0) ""
  protected $withParams =>
  array(0) {
  }
  protected $aliasName =>
  NULL
  protected $via =>
  NULL
  protected $noLoad =>
  bool(false)
  protected $all =>
  bool(false)
}


MODEL:
NULL
```

Clearly there is data in the bean, so why does `box()` return `NULL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it was a namespacing problem.

The [documentation](http://www.redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/models) says that

> If you like your models to reside in the namespace \Model, you can set the following constant:
>
> ```
>    //with namespace Model
>    define( 'REDBEAN_MODEL_PREFIX', '\\Model\\' )
> ```
>
> You can now create a model class like this:
>
> ```
>    class \Model\Band extends \RedBeanPHP\SimpleModel { ... }
> ```

The phrasing "... you *can* set ..." led me to believe that it's optional. However, it turns out that if you like your models to reside in the namespace \Model, and you want to be able to use FUSE methods, you **MUST** set the above constant and you **MUST** call your model class `Band`.

Also, note that you **MUST** use double backslashes (`\\`) everywhere when you define that namespace string.

To add to the confusion, right before the above documentation paragraph, there is a paragraph saying

> RedBeanPHP automatically connects beans with models using a naming convention (i.e. Model_{TYPE OF BEAN}).

Apparently, you should use the naming convention `Model_Band` when **NOT** using namespaces, and the naming convention `Band` when you do, or things break down.